# Making a Floating TPopupMenu

Tags: delphi

How can I make the Tpopupmenu to support floating, so that user can drag and drop the menu items (sub menus) to all around the user's desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menus do not support that capability.  Any dragging you want to perform will have to be implemented using your own windows.